# jsonpath for nested arrays in kubectl get

Tags: kubectl, jsonpath

I am trying to get the resource limits & requests for Kubernetes pods. I am attempting to output to a comma delimited row that lists the namespace, pod name, container name and then the mem & CPU limits/requests for each container. Running into issues when there's multiple containers per pod.

The closest I've been able to get is this which will print out a single row for each pod. If there are multiple containers, they are listed in separate "columns" in the same row.

`kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{range .items[*]}{@.metadata.namespace}{","}{@.metadata.name}{","}{range .spec.containers[*]}{.name}{","}{@.resources.requests.cpu}{","}{@.resources.requests.memory}{","}{@.resources.limits.cpu}{","}{@.resources.limits.memory}{","}{end}{"\n"}{end}'`

The output looks like this:

```
kube-system,metrics-server-5f8d84558d-g926z,metrics-server-vpa,5m,30Mi,100m,300Mi,metrics-server,46m,63Mi,46m,63Mi,
```

What I would like to see is something like this:

```
kube-system,metrics-server-5f8d84558d-g926z,metrics-server-vpa,5m,30Mi,100m,300Mi,
kube-system,metrics-server-5f8d84558d-g926z,metrics-server,46m,63Mi,46m,63Mi,
```

Appreciate any assistance. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think (don't know that) you **can't** using only `kubectl`'s (limited) JSONPath.

There's a UNIX principle that each tool should do one thing well:

- `kubectl` does Kubernetes stuff well and can output JSON
- [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) does JSON processing well.

If you're willing to use another tool:

```bash
FILTER='
  .items[]
  |.metadata as $meta
  |.spec.containers[]
  |.name as $name
  |.resources.requests as $requests
  |.resources.limits as $limits
  |[ 
     $meta.namespace,
     $meta.name,$name,
     $requests.cpu,
     $requests.memory,
     $limits.cpu,
     $limits.memory
   ]
  |@csv
'

kubectl get pods \
--all-namespaces \
--output=json \
| jq -r "${FILTER}"
```

Explanation:

1. For each `items` (i.e. each Pod)
2. Set the variable `meta` to the (Pod's) `metadata` content
3. For each `containers` (i.e. each Container)
4. Set the variable `name` as the (Container's) `name`
5. Set the variable `requests` as the (Container's Resources') `requests`
6. Set the variable `limits` as the (Container's Resources') `limits`
7. Create an array (`[...]`) by reassembling the relevant pieces
8. Output the arrays as comma-delimited

On a cluster:

```
"monitoring","prometheus-adapter-59df95d9f5-kg4hc","prometheus-adapter",,,,
"monitoring","prometheus-adapter-59df95d9f5-j6rbx","prometheus-adapter",,,,
"monitoring","prometheus-operator-7775c66ccf-45z2f","prometheus-operator","100m","100Mi","200m","200Mi"
"monitoring","prometheus-operator-7775c66ccf-45z2f","kube-rbac-proxy","10m","20Mi","20m","40Mi"
"monitoring","node-exporter-7cf4m","node-exporter","102m","180Mi","250m","180Mi"
"monitoring","node-exporter-7cf4m","kube-rbac-proxy","10m","20Mi","20m","40Mi"
"monitoring","kube-state-metrics-76f6cb7996-hdxcb","kube-state-metrics","10m","190Mi","100m","250Mi"
"monitoring","kube-state-metrics-76f6cb7996-hdxcb","kube-rbac-proxy-main","20m","20Mi","40m","40Mi"
"monitoring","kube-state-metrics-76f6cb7996-hdxcb","kube-rbac-proxy-self","10m","20Mi","20m","40Mi"
"monitoring","blackbox-exporter-55c457d5fb-x6hwj","blackbox-exporter","10m","20Mi","20m","40Mi"
"monitoring","blackbox-exporter-55c457d5fb-x6hwj","module-configmap-reloader","10m","20Mi","20m","40Mi"
"monitoring","blackbox-exporter-55c457d5fb-x6hwj","kube-rbac-proxy","10m","20Mi","20m","40Mi"
"monitoring","grafana-6dd5b5f65-6jwq8","grafana","100m","100Mi","200m","200Mi"
"monitoring","alertmanager-main-0","alertmanager","4m","100Mi","100m","100Mi"
"monitoring","alertmanager-main-0","config-reloader","100m","50Mi","100m","50Mi"
"kube-system","coredns-7f9c69c78c-2zx4h","coredns","100m","70Mi",,"170Mi"
"monitoring","prometheus-k8s-0","prometheus",,"400Mi",,
"monitoring","prometheus-k8s-0","config-reloader","100m","50Mi","100m","50Mi"
"kube-system","calico-kube-controllers-5f7575cc96-6tf8x","calico-kube-controllers",,,,
"kube-system","calico-node-m78xm","calico-node","250m",,,
```

Comment: This is awesome. Seeing I didn't really know anything about jsonpath until today, I'm totally open to whatever if it gets the job done. Now I need to dig into jq! Thanks so much.

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm interested to know whether anyone can show how to do what you want with `kubectl`'s implementation of JSONPath (it's not a full JSONPath implementation). But, `jq` is a good tool (there are others that you may prefer).

Comment: Also appreciate the detailed explanation. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to obtain the output natively using `kubectl` via the `go-template` output format. `jsonpath` is not the right tool(maybe doable) for this requirement; perhaps piping to `jq` or `go-template` is the appropriate solution.

```
kubectl get pod -o go-template='{{- range $index, $element := .items -}}
                                  {{- range $container, $status := $element.spec.containers -}}
                                    {{- printf "%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s\n" $element.metadata.namespace  $element.metadata.name  $status.name (or $status.resources.requests.cpu "" ) (or $status.resources.requests.memory "") (or $status.resources.limits.memory "") (or $status.resources.limits.cpu "") -}}
                                    {{- end -}}
                                {{- end -}}'
```

Comment: Nice! I forget that `kubectl` supports Go templates.